# Word embedding vectors for keyphrase extraction

Tags: nlp, text-mining, word2vec, word-embeddings

I am just interested to know if we can use the generated word embedding vectors to extract keywords from a document or not.

If yes, how?

Comment: Perhaps your can have a look at this tutorial :- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec and the basic tutorial sample code (convert vocabulary to embedding) :- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py The actual implementation for Mikolov, et. al is available here.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec.py

Comment: What technique are you using for keyphrase extraction? Is your problem supervised? Unsupervised?

Answer (score 1):

Word embeddings are just a way to represent tokens (often words, but could be characters) in a way that it inherently carries semantic meaning (i.e. as opposed to simply one-hot encoding), but **it is not a keyphrase extraction technique**.

Word embeddings can help you extract key phrases better because they will make your input more meaningful, but unless you have a technique to extract such phrases, they won't help you.